# Issue with MIUI status bar theming

Tags: android, android-theme, miui

I'm trying to achieve transparent status bar in MIUI.

I've tried everything from styles to window flags but nothing works.

[image: ScreenShot]

Theme :

```
 <!-- Status bar. -->
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

And window flags

```
 window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
    val decorView = window.decorView
    decorView.fitsSystemWindows = true
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

What else can I do to hide the status bar ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` from `window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = ...`

Comment: Still doesn't work, now the status bar is black instead of white

Answer (score 0):

These resources helped me solve the issue

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-going-edge-to-edge-812f62e4e83e

And a codelab

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/gesture-navigation#3